# Connect to a remote host from terminal works but not from deployment

Tags: server, pycharm, remote-server

I was trying to connect to a remote server from the terminal (PyCharm IDE in Mac), and it works.

[image: connecting from terminal]

I tried to connect to the same remote host from Deployment to see the files on the server, and I am getting the error

> "host not found"

connecting from tools->deployment->brows remote host error

[image: connecting from tools->deployment->brows remote host error]

Comment: When doing the same thing from another computer, it works- both with the same Pycharm professional  version 2021.2.3 and running on mac ..

Comment: You can try to check your credentials for non-English/ASCII symbols.